# AVAudioSession setActive throws error 561015905 in Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios-keyboard-extension

I am trying to record and play audio from keyboard extension in Swift, but it throws an error on line `recordingSession.setActive(true)`

Error:
failed to record The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 561015905.)

I have already set the key RequestsOpenAccess to true in info.plist and granted full access to the keyboard extension.

Comment: Never tried activating an audio session from a keyboard extension myself, but the error seems to be this one, if that helps: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/errorcode/cannotstartplaying

Comment: Thanks but the application is in foreground when I'm recording and I've already given full access to the keyboard extension.

Comment: And, just to make sure, have you added a microphone usage description to the extension’s Info.plist?

Comment: @adeasismont Yes, I have.